# react-native-fs [Error: Directory could not be created]

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I am trying to create a directory using `RNFS.mkdir`, but it's warning "Directory could not be created"...

```
"react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
"react-native": "0.64.0",
```

The function that I use to write is the following:

```
const phoneStorageDir = RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + '/MyApp/pictures/';

const createAppFolder = async () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        {
          title: 'Permissions for write access',
          message: 'Give permission to your storage to write a file',
          buttonPositive: 'ok',
        },
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        await RNFS.mkdir(phoneStorageDir);
      } else {
        console.log('permission denied');
        return;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

I've also added to it's manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And even added a prop on `<application>` tag `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` as suggested by some other users, while I was searching for this...

Another weird behaviour, is the fact that my app isn't asking for permissions (not even on physical device), although it's granted as soon as I compile the app, as follows:

[image: Sh*ts crazy]

Comment: Hi , Im facing the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: Has this issue been resolved?

Answer (score 9):

In the library RNFS, the `RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath` takes a path that is not allowed on version 11.

Use custom path, just replace `ExternalStorageDirectoryPath` with `/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/{$packagename}`

Android for version below 10, your old code will work fine.